# Oracle SQL error with parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below Oracle SQL Query that keeps giving me an error. I get missing right parenthesis error. I tried looking for the missing parenthesis but they all seem to close correctly in the notepad editor.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEES.NAME FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE Employees.EmployeeID NOT IN 
(
SELECT Services.EmployeeID FROM Services where 

SERVICES.CHECKOUT <>3 AND SERVICES.CHECKOUT <> 5 AND SERVICES.CHECKOUT <>6
AND 
(
TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' BETWEEN SERVICES.STARTDATE AND SERVICES.ENDDATE) or  
TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' BETWEEN SERVICES.STARTDATE AND SERVICES.ENDDATE) or
SERVICES.STARTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') or
SERVICES.ENDDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
)

union

SELECT EMPBREAKS.EMPID FROM EMPBREAKS WHERE
TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.STARTB AND EMPBREAKS.ENDB or 
TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.STARTB AND EMPBREAKS.ENDB or 
EMPBREAKS.STARTB BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') or
EMPBREAKS.ENDB BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') or
(EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC =1 AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE('11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')) or
(EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC =1 AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE('11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')) or
(EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC =1 AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND TO_DATE('11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')) or
(EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC =1 AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB, 'HH24:MI:SS', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')))
union
SELECT EMPSICKVACATIONS.EMP_NO FROM EMPSICKVACATIONS  Where EMPSICKVACATIONS.VDATE = TO_DATE('19/06/2017 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') or (EMPSICKVACATIONS.CYCLICFLAG = 1 AND EMPSICKVACATIONS.WEEKDAYINDEX = 4))
```

Comment: Post (add to your question) the error you get.

Comment: You might want to remove all _useless_ parentheses first - then it might be easier to spot the problem (e.g. there is no need to put each select of a union between parentheses, there is no need to put the select of sub-query between parentheses, there is no need to put the whole where clause between parentheses, ...)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a parenthesis-counting service.

Comment: Queries like that make my eyeballs bleed.  Build it again from where you started, adding a pair at a time, only when necessary.  Add water and plenty of plant food.

Comment: Whilst the other comments are correct and you need to learn how to structure code so that you CAN debug it I think you should look at the fourth line from the bottom of your listing and see if everything looks OK.

Answer (score 2):

Although you haven't given us an idea of what kind of error is produced by this query, Oracle quite often doesn't like multiple left-parentheses together, especially when they're not needed. Also, you're using the same constants over and over again - best to put these in a table expression and then cross-join this to your subqueries to avoid having to retype them multiple times. Reformatting your query to eliminate unneeded parentheses, make it a bit more readable, and to use the table expression to eliminate the constants we get:

```
WITH QUERY_DATA AS (SELECT TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DT11,
                           TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DT12,
                           TO_DATE('11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AS HH11,
                           TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AS HH12)
SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID, EMPLOYEES.NAME
  FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID NOT IN
          (SELECT SERVICES.EMPLOYEEID
             FROM SERVICES
             CROSS JOIN QUERY_DATA q
             WHERE SERVICES.CHECKOUT <> 3 AND
                   SERVICES.CHECKOUT <> 5 AND
                   SERVICES.CHECKOUT <> 6 AND 
                  (q.DT11 BETWEEN SERVICES.STARTDATE
                              AND SERVICES.ENDDATE OR
                   q.DT12 BETWEEN SERVICES.STARTDATE
                              AND SERVICES.ENDDATE OR
                   SERVICES.STARTDATE BETWEEN q.DT11
                                          AND q.DT12 OR
                   SERVICES.ENDDATE BETWEEN q.DT11
                                        AND q.DT12)
           UNION
           SELECT EMPBREAKS.EMPID
             FROM EMPBREAKS
             CROSS JOIN QUERY_DATA
             WHERE q.DT11 BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.STARTB
                              AND EMPBREAKS.ENDB OR
                   q.DT12 BETWEEN EMPBREAKS.STARTB
                              AND EMPBREAKS.ENDB OR
                   EMPBREAKS.STARTB BETWEEN q.DT12
                                        AND q.DT11 OR
                   EMPBREAKS.ENDB BETWEEN q.DT12
                                      AND q.DT11 OR
                  (EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC = 1 AND
                   EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND
                   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN q.HH11
                                                                                    AND q.HH12) OR
                  (EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC = 1 AND
                   EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND
                   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN q.HH11
                                                                                  AND q.HH12) OR
                  (EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC = 1 AND
                   EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND
                   q.HH11 BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB, 'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')
                              AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')) OR
                  (EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC = 1 AND
                   EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4 AND
                   q.HH12 BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB, 'HH24:MI:SS', 'HH24:MI:SS')
                              AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS')))
           UNION
           SELECT EMPSICKVACATIONS.EMP_NO
             FROM EMPSICKVACATIONS
             Where EMPSICKVACATIONS.VDATE = TO_DATE('19/06/2017 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') OR
                   (EMPSICKVACATIONS.CYCLICFLAG = 1 AND
                    EMPSICKVACATIONS.WEEKDAYINDEX = 4))
```

Looking at this a bit you'll notice that in the second query in the `UNION` there's a couple expressions which look like

```
               EMPBREAKS.STARTB BETWEEN q.DT12
                                    AND q.DT11 OR
               EMPBREAKS.ENDB BETWEEN q.DT12
                                  AND q.DT11 OR
```

These will be a problem because the first date (QUERY_DATA.DT12) is greater than the second date (QUERY_DATA.DT11). In a `BETWEEN` expression the first value must be less than or equal to the second value or the expression will never be satisfied. These should be rewritten as

```
               EMPBREAKS.STARTB BETWEEN q.DT11
                                    AND q.DT12 OR
               EMPBREAKS.ENDB BETWEEN q.DT11
                                  AND q.DT12 OR
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For solving these problems

1. Use Code beautifier/formatter feature of your SQL developer clients, suggestion is to Use one, since there are so many cool features.
2. Copy the code and hit the shortcut to format code
3. Your code formatting would either break, where there is an issue or it would highlight
4. Code formatting can be adjusted, since most editors have that feature.

`SELECT EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEEID,
    EMPLOYEES.NAME
        FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE Employees.EmployeeID NOT IN (
        (
            SELECT Services.EmployeeID
            FROM Services
            WHERE
                (
                    (
                        SERVICES.CHECKOUT <>3
                    AND SERVICES.CHECKOUT <> 5
                    AND SERVICES.CHECKOUT <>6
                    )
                AND
                    (
                        (
                            TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN
                            SERVICES.STARTDATE AND SERVICES.ENDDATE
                        )
                     OR
                        (
                            TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN
                            SERVICES.STARTDATE AND SERVICES.ENDDATE
                        )
                     OR
                        (
                            SERVICES.STARTDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00',
                            'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00',
                            'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                        )
                     OR
                        (
                            SERVICES.ENDDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00',
                            'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00',
                            'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
    UNION
        (
            SELECT EMPBREAKS.EMPID
            FROM EMPBREAKS
            WHERE
                (
                    (
                        TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN
                        EMPBREAKS.STARTB AND EMPBREAKS.ENDB
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN
                        EMPBREAKS.STARTB AND EMPBREAKS.ENDB
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        EMPBREAKS.STARTB BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
                        ) AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        EMPBREAKS.ENDB BETWEEN TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                        AND TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC   =1
                    AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4
                    AND
                        (
                            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN
                            TO_DATE('11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
                        )
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC   =1
                    AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4
                    AND
                        (
                            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE(
                            '11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS')
                        )
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC   =1
                    AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4
                    AND
                        (
                            TO_DATE('11:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB,
                            'HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'
                            ),'HH24:MI:SS')
                        )
                    )
                 OR
                    (
                        EMPBREAKS.FLAGCYCLIC   =1
                    AND EMPBREAKS.DAYWEEKINDEX = 4
                    AND
                        (
                            TO_DATE('12:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS') BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.STARTB,
                            'HH24:MI:SS', 'HH24:MI:SS')) AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(EMPBREAKS.ENDB,'HH24:MI:SS'
                            ),'HH24:MI:SS'))
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
    UNION
        (
            SELECT EMPSICKVACATIONS.EMP_NO
            FROM EMPSICKVACATIONS
            WHERE EMPSICKVACATIONS.VDATE = TO_DATE('19/06/2017 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
             OR
                (
                    EMPSICKVACATIONS.CYCLICFLAG   = 1
                AND EMPSICKVACATIONS.WEEKDAYINDEX = 4
                )
        )
        );`

Comment: I'm amazed this beautifier didn't throw a 'stack overflow' error on that SQL :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the end brackets off your first couple of to_date's:

```
TO_DATE('29/06/2017 11:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' BETWEEN SERVICES.STARTDATE AND SERVICES.ENDDATE) or  
TO_DATE('29/06/2017 12:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' BETWEEN SERVICES.STARTDATE AND SERVICES.ENDDATE) or
```

Also, it looks like you're trying to see if the start and end dates of two periods overlap - typically you can do that with:

```
and period1.start_date <= period2.end_date
and period1.end_date >= period2.start_date
```

which is much simpler and easier to grasp, IMHO.